# HDMI to RGB conversion

Tags: display, rgb, hdmi

I am working on a HDMI dongle based on I.MX6Q with reference to the design files shared in Freescale community.

I want to feed HDMI input to processor. As there is no HDMI input available with I.MX6Q processor, I am considering to use camera input port (described in section 37.1.2.1.1 of I.MXQ Reference manual) which is having parallel input upto 20 bits & I2S interface for audio connectivity.

But the HDMI receivers available in market like ADV7611 come with 24 bit RGB interface. As our processor input port has only 20 bits, we will have to ignore 4 LSBs in total(we havent finalized the bits to be ignored).

**Are there any drawbacks to this approach in terms of picture quality?**

Also, **are there other means of converting HDMI to some serial interface that will be available in I.MX6?**

Answer (score 1):

The 24 bit data is split into 8 bits red, green and blue. 8b colour means that there are 256 different possible colours.

So if you drop 1 lsb off red and blue and 2 lsb off the green (for example), then you are only going to have 64 possible shades of green instead of 255.

[This article](http://compreviews.about.com/od/multimedia/a/LCDColor.htm) compares the difference between 8b and 6b visually.